# RS Revelation '11 dual air fork leaks

Tags: repair, fork, suspension

I have a RS Revelation dual air fork. It's new, never used before. I installed it and after a few days I noticed, that it loses air. Maybe 20-30 psi over night. So at morning it's just too soft and have a sag around 40% (way too much).
Air leask from both positive and negative chambers.

Is it normal for this fork or should I check any specific parts of this fork?
Please note, that there's no RS service center in my city or anywhere nearby and I would prefer to fix problems (if any) by myself.

Comment: If it's brand new, send it back to be repaired under warranty. They shouldn't be doing that!

Comment: Are you setting it to the recommended PSI for your weight and sag? It's possible if you are over inflating that its maxed out and leaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found [this technical manual](http://cdn.sram.com/cdn/farfuture/AI2eab6UCQXF2oI6WYGjmfGn2AKwj8ORWSnDla3YG14/mtime:1301946040/sites/default/files/techdocs/2011-revelation-technical-manual.pdf) for RS Revelation 2011 to be extremely usrfull. I removed lower legs and relubricated dual air spring.
Everything is simple enough if you have appropriate tools.

I should note that grease in air spring was very strange: it was partly liquid and partly it still was viscous. Anyway, I removed all of this grease and applied new to o-rings and top-cap thread. By now (2 to 3 weeks later) fork didn't lose any significant amount of pressure anymore, so that worked fine.

Please note that you will need to add 5 to 8ml (it's maximum) of 5w fork oil to lower legs. *(I used 10w fork oil for this purpose and didn't feel any difference)*
And if you want to service your damper cartridge you will need 123ml 15w fork oil for **Motion Control** cartridge, and 133ml 15w fork oil for **BlackBox** cartridge.

And here's a link to page, where you can find all [technical manuals for Revelation forks](http://www.sram.com/service/rockshox/7,107,434).

Answer (score 1):

I have never had experience with an RS Revelation fork, but you might find this [forum post](http://forums.mtbr.com/all-mountain/fork-problem-leaking-negative-air-pressue-638039.html) useful. Common solutions seem to be taking the fork apart, cleaning, and re-oiling the o-rings. Good luck!